# Is it safe to call impure functions in aggregates?

Tags: postgresql, aggregate

In the following example, I'm trying to assign an ID from a sequence to each group of rows from table `source`, so that I can later insert those rows into one table as well as insert aggregates for each group into another table, with foreign keys pointing from the first to the second table. The IDs serve as the primary key in the aggregate table. I'm trying to do this without creating the aggregates first, because then I'd have to join with `source` again to get the IDs, which involves quite complicated expressions in my actual project.

The solution I came up is taking an ID from the sequence for each source row instead of each group, but only using the lowest one, using a partition. This will of course "waste" some IDs, but I'm not concerned about that:

```sql
create temporary sequence foo_seq start 1000;

create temporary table source(id, data) as (
    values
        (1, 'a'),
        (2, 'b'),
        (3, 'b'),
        (4, 'c'),
        (5, 'c'),
        (6, 'c'));

select
    id,
    data,
    min(nextval('foo_seq'::regclass)) over (partition by data) as group_id
from
    source;
```

Is this safe to do? I.e. is it guaranteed that `min(nextval('foo_seq'::regclass))` will actually output the same value for each row within a group? I'm worried e.g. about `min()` being re-evaluated for the whole group in some circumstance, which wouldn't be a problem if `nextval()` were a pure function (without side effects). It seems to work in this example:

```
 id | data | group_id 
----+------+----------
  1 | a    |     1000
  2 | b    |     1001
  3 | b    |     1001
  4 | c    |     1003
  5 | c    |     1003
  6 | c    |     1003
```

Answer (score 2):

A typical solution in such case is *not* to generate a new `key` but to *reuse* the original `key` of the table.

```
select
    id,
    data,
    min(id) over (partition by data) as group_id
from
    source;  

id|data|group_id|
--+----+--------+
 1|a   |       1|
 2|b   |       2|
 3|b   |       2|
 4|c   |       4|
 5|c   |       4|
 6|c   |       4|
```

Your proposal even if it is *safe* in the means that *analytic MIN* will provide the same value for each member of the group (partition) seems a bit *ugly*.

**Discussion**

The usage of *sequences* shine in highly `OLTP` processing with lot of concurrent transaction.

*Aggregation jobs* are typically a *dispositive* tasks done in a *single* job (without concurrency).

In this context is valid (and effective) to use instead of `nextval()` simple `max(id) + 1` - in your case *if you want to keep the `group_id` unique* you can add some constant calculated as a *maximum* existing `id` in the target (aggregated) table.

```
 1000 + min(id) over (partition by data) as group_id
```

The details depend on your use case that you do not show.

Comment: The problem is that the table I'm inserting into already contains some rows, that's why I'm using the sequence of the table's primary key to generate IDs.

Comment: Added some explanation @Feuermurmel to the answer

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I see that you are trying to help me with the alternative approach that you're describing. But it does not answer my question. I'm well aware of alternatives to my solution and I have already implemented one in the project I'm working on. But Id still like to understand the implications of the approach described in the question.